# IF and AND in Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet with many sheets which is used for requirement gathering. the stakeholder fills the data in every sheet

Now, some fields in each spreadsheet are very critical, hence we plan to highlight in some manner and the validation to take place

1. Once a sheet is filled the stakeholder will click on a button
2. This button will check if the mandatory fields are filled
3. If those cells are empty, a toast notification will pop up mentioning what is to be filled along with highlighting the cells in red color
4. After the stakeholder fills the info, hits validate button again, the same check happens and colors the cell background to white and display another toast pop up if all is ok.

I have following data in the google sheet
[image]

I wrote this apps script to have the validation stated in the above 4 points, as I am new to google apps script, I am facing difficulty with some bits of it

```
function toastMessageTitle() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rg1= sheet.getRange('B2');
  var rg1_lbl = sheet.getRange('A2').getValue();
  var rg2 = sheet.getRange('B5')
  var rg2_lbl = sheet.getRange('A5').getValue();
  var rg3 = sheet.getRange('B8')
  var rg3_lbl = sheet.getRange('A8').getValue();
  if (rg1.isBlank() && rg2.isBlank() && rg3.isBlank())
  { SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Please fill - " + rg1_lbl+ ", " + rg2_lbl + ", " + rg3_lbl , "⚠️ Unfilled data",10);
    rg1.setBackgroundColor("red");
    rg2.setBackgroundColor("red");
    rg3.setBackgroundColor("red");
  }
  else
 { SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("All filled", "Thank you",10);
  
  }
}
```

Please help how can I get the validation done.

Comment: "I am facing difficulty with some bits of it" <-- Please explain precisely and clearly what bits of it

Comment: What parts of it are you facing difficulty with? Please include what you have tried, what hasn't worked, and the result you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script you can use to achieve this:

```js
function toastMessageTitle() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rg1= sheet.getRange('B2');
  //var rg1_lbl = sheet.getRange('A2').getValue();
  var rg2 = sheet.getRange('B5')
  //var rg2_lbl = sheet.getRange('A5').getValue();
  var rg3 = sheet.getRange('B8')
  //var rg3_lbl = sheet.getRange('A8').getValue();

  var ranges = [rg1, rg2, rg3];
  var unfilled = [];

  for(var range of ranges) {
    if(range.isBlank()) {
      unfilled.push(range.offset(0,-1).getValue())
      range.setBackground('red');
      } else {range.setBackground(null)};
  }

  if(unfilled.length == 0) SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("All filled", "Thank you",10);
  else {
    unfilled = unfilled.join(", ");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Please fill - " + unfilled, "⚠️ Unfilled data",10);
  }
}
```

This script simply goes through the different ranges, checks if they are blank, and then proceeds accordingly. If none of the cells are blank (ie the `unfilled` array has nothing in it), it shows the success message.

[image: ex]